# Rending elements based on Promises in React (Firebase Storage)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-storage

Works:

```
render() {

    const storageRef = firebase.storage().ref();


    const nice = Object.keys(this.state.photos).map((key) => {
        return <div>{key}</div>;        
    });


return(
    {nice}
)
```

Does not work:

```
render() {

    const storageRef = firebase.storage().ref();


    const nice = Object.keys(this.state.photos).map((key) => {
        storageRef.child('front.jpg').getDownloadURL().then(function(url) {
            return <div><img src={url} /></div>;        
        )}
    });


return(
    {nice}
)
```

The `.then` stuff seems to break the rendering in React. I can see `nice` is all good and proper in the console, but nothing comes out on the DOM. The idea of the code is to store names of images in state (which reference images in our Firebase Storage) and then render each image after fetching the URLs using `getDownloadURL`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Promises are asynchronous. Your code above is going to return {nice} every single time because while the promise is waiting to be fulfilled, the next line of code will be returned, which is return ({nice}), which will be undefined. Putting a promise in your render method is just bad practice in general. In fact ideally, your entire component would be a pure function (ie it just renders based on the props it receives and the asynchronous stuff is handled somewhere else, like in a redux thunk or saga, but we'll come back to that in a bit.

The proper way to handle asynchronous code within a component is by using react's [lifecycle methods](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html). Using lifecycle methods in turn requires that you define your components as classes that extend React.Component (see the link). Which lifecycle method you put your async function (promise) in depends on when you need your asynchronous code to run. For example, if you just want the code to run whenever the component is first rendered, you might want to use the "componentWillMount" method or even just the constructor. For example, something like this:

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    this.state = {
      photoUrl: ''
    }
    storageRef.child('front.jpg').getDownloadURL().then(function(url) {
        this.setState({photoUrl: url})        
    )}
  }

  render(){
    if(this.state.photoUrl){
      return (<div><img src={this.state.url} /></div>)
    } else {
      return '' //will return nothing until you actually have a url
    }
  }
}
```

The promise will only run once, when the component is first being rendered. For more flexibility, check out the lifecycle methods. If you want asynchronous code to run in response to a user interaction, define your own function that houses the promise and updates state when it completes. Then in your html element, reference that function like so:

```
<input ... onClick={this.myAsyncFn.bind(this)}/>
```

Ok, so back to what I said about redux. You may not need it right now, but as you continue down this path of react development you will definitely want it. And based on your title where you say you are using Firebase as your store, I'm guessing you may not fully understand what the redux store is used for. It is a state management solution. Why would you need this? Well for example, what if another component needed that url you just retrieved? Would it have to make an async call too? You could have a higher level component that makes the async call and passes the url down to its children via props, but what if that doesn't really make sense for your app? Further more, what if your user needs to navigate to a different page where that component doesn't exist, but that url is also needed on that other page? Do you need to go get it again? Making so many calls to Firebase isn't really efficient, so what if we just put all the stuff we needed related to our state (like an "appIsBusy" flag) and data (like urls we are keeping track of) that we are working with all in one place? That is the redux store. Redux thunk and redux sagas are just ways of handling all the asynchronous things (and other stuff, but dont worry about it right now) that can happen in your app in a way that is external to your components. That means that your components can all be pure functions that just take props and render based on what they are given. They do not need to do anything asynchronous themselves, and will always behave predictably. That said, my recommendation is to look at the redux library ([here](http://redux.js.org/)) and try integrating it with your app (you'll also need the react-redux library. [This is a helpful article](http://www.sohamkamani.com/blog/2017/03/31/react-redux-connect-explained/) to better understand what is going on with that). Don't worry about thunks or sagas yet, just handle your asynch stuff in your components using the lifecycle methods as shown above. Then when you get a handle on all of that, you can start looking into thunks and sagas.

Answer (score 0):

You need to return a single element wrapper inside your render function.

So it should be

```
return (<div>{photosArray}</div>)
```

You also have a typo, the array is used as both : photosArray and photosarray

Comment: Thanks, but I've done some playing around and realised it's the promise that's breaking this, rather than the stuff you mentioned (which was sort of hacked down from the real code I'm running).